# How to remove one subset from an array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array such as: `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]`
And I want to remove this array of elements `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
So in the end I want to be left with `[1, 2, 3]`

I have tried using the method below but it removes all copies of the elements from the main array.

```
myArray = myArray.filter( function( el ) {
  return !toRemove.includes( el );
} );
```

Comment: Are both arrays always sorted?

Comment: create an object that will have first array values as keys and number of that values as value, forEach the second array and substract 1 from each key from first array

Comment: @MarkMeyer No, not necessarily sorted.

Comment: _"And I want to remove this array of elements"_ Do you mean remove the elements from the original array or return a new array containing only the elements not included within `toRemove`? Is `myArray = myArray.filter()` intentionally redefining `myArray` as the result of `.filter()`, which returns a new array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `filter`, `indexOf` and `splice`.

```js
const input = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5];

function removeSubset(arr, subset) {
  const exclude = [...subset];
  return arr.filter(x => {
    const idx = exclude.indexOf(x);
    if (idx >= 0) {
      exclude.splice(idx, 1);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
}

console.log(removeSubset(input, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**Shitf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [**Sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
let arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
let remove  = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5].sort((a,b)=>a-b)

let op = arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b).filter(e => ( remove.includes(e) ? (remove.shift(), false) : true ))


console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is looping on the array of elements to remove and for each one remove the first element found on the input array:

```js
const input = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5];

const removeItems = (input, items) =>
{
    // Make a copy, to not mutate the input.
    let clonedInput = input.slice();

    // Search and remove items.
    items.forEach(x =>
    {
        let i = clonedInput.findIndex(y => y === x);
        if (i >= 0) clonedInput.splice(i, 1);
    });
    
    return clonedInput;
}

console.log(removeItems(input, [1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(removeItems(input, [1,2]));
console.log(removeItems(input, [1,99,44,5]));
```

If you still want to use filter, you can use the items to remove as the `this` argument of the filter, something like this:

```js
const input = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5];

const removeItems = (input, items) =>
{        
    return input.filter(function(x)
    {
        let i = this.findIndex(y => y === x);
        return i >= 0 ? (this.splice(i, 1), false) : true;
    }, items.slice());
}

console.log(removeItems(input, [1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(removeItems(input, [1,2]));
console.log(removeItems(input, [1,99,44,5]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get a `Map` and count the values and filter by checking the count and decrement the count if found.

```js
var array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5],
    remove = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    map = remove.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map),
    result = array.filter(v => !map.get(v) || !map.set(v, map.get(v) - 1));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: And where is the array of the elements to remove? What is just want to remove elements `[1,2]`?

Comment: This now only works if the removal array is sorted, which is why I asked about it in the comment.

Comment: Ja, that seems like the most reasonable way to do this without getting quadratic complexity.